# selenium returning empty text

Tags: c#, selenium

Following a tutorial to test search functionality on wikipedia using c#. My test keeps failing because the the text from the h1 element im trying to return keeps returning empty. There is definitely text inside the h1 header. Any idea why This element is returning empty when it has text?

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");

IWebElement searchInput = driver.FindElement(By.Id("searchInput"));
searchInput.SendKeys("Christiaan Barnard");
searchInput.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

IWebElement firstHeading = driver.FindElement(By.Id("firstHeading"));
Assert.AreEqual("Christiaan Barnard", firstHeading.Text);
driver.Quit();
```

Comment: Depending on how the search on Wikipedia works, you might need to put an artificial wait in to ensure the page has rendered correctly first.

Comment: As @simonlchilds already suggested. I think your page is not loaded when you execute the line `driver.FindElement(By.Id("firstHeading"));`. Try to wait for some seconds and check again.

Comment: you guys were right thanks

Answer (score 1):

It may be because the element is found, but does not yet have the expected value. The best approach is to wait until the text has the expected value, using WebDriverWait:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var result = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementLocated(By.Id("firstHeading"), "Christiaan Barnard"));
Assert.IsTrue(result);
```